# How do I create a show/hide loop in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my HTML with 3 questions and 3 answers:

```
<div class="faq-carousel">
<div class="all-questions question1">
    <h4>Question 1</h4>
</div>
<div class="all-questions question2">
    <h4>Question 2</h4>
</div>
<div class="all-questions question3">
    <h4>Question 3</h4>
</div>

<div class=" all-answers answer1">
    <p>Answer 1</p>
</div>              
<div class=" all-answers answer2">
    <p>Answer 2</p>
</div>  
<div class=" all-answers answer3">
    <p>Answer 3</p>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery that shows/hides the 3 questions and answers:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

"use strict";

jQuery(".all-answers").hide();
jQuery(".answer1").show();
jQuery(".all-questions").removeClass("highlighted");
jQuery(".question1").addClass("highlighted");

var slideNumber = 1;
jQuery(".question1").click(function () {
    jQuery(".all-answers").hide();
    jQuery(".answer1").show();
    jQuery(".all-questions").removeClass("highlighted");
    jQuery(".question1").addClass("highlighted");
    slideNumber = 1;
});

jQuery(".question2").click(function () {
    jQuery(".all-answers").hide();
    jQuery(".answer2").show();
    jQuery(".all-questions").removeClass("highlighted");
    jQuery(".question2").addClass("highlighted");
    slideNumber = 2;
});

jQuery(".question3").click(function () {
    jQuery(".all-answers").hide();
    jQuery(".answer3").show();
    jQuery(".all-questions").removeClass("highlighted");
    jQuery(".question3").addClass("highlighted");
    slideNumber = 3;
}); });
```

How can I change the jQuery so that I can add more Q and A's to the HMTL without having to add more jQuery?

Many thanks!

Comment: by referencing to eachother. Eg. try to add `data-xxx` attributes to the questions

Comment: Thanks giorgio, although I am very new to jQuery - could you provide an example? I appreciate your time.

Comment: You could do something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/w3xe1am8/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The process you're trying to achieve here is to 'DRY' up your code, in other words, Don't Repeat Yourself.

To achieve what you need you can use common classes on the questions and answers, then relate the two together by their indexes, something like this:

```js
"use strict";

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.question').click(function() {
    $('.question').removeClass('highlighted');
    var index = $(this).addClass('highlighted').index();
    $('.answer').hide().eq(index).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.answer { display: block; }
.answer ~ .answer { display: none; }
.highlighted { background-color: #CC0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq-carousel">
  <div class="question">
    <h4>Question 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="question">
    <h4>Question 2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="question">
    <h4>Question 3</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="answer">
    <p>Answer 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>Answer 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>Answer 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you want to explicitly link the elements together, due to HTML structure restrictions for example, then you can use `data` attributes to specify the relationships between elements:

```js
"use strict";

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.question').click(function() {
    $('.question').removeClass('highlighted');
    var target = $(this).addClass('highlighted').data('target');
    $('.answer').hide().filter(target).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.answer { display: block; }
.answer ~ .answer { display: none; }
.highlighted { background-color: #CC0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq-carousel">
  <div class="question" data-target="#answer-01">
    <h4>Question 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="question" data-target="#answer-02">
    <h4>Question 2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="question" data-target="#answer-03">
    <h4>Question 3</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="answer" id="answer-01">
    <p>Answer 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="answer" id="answer-02">
    <p>Answer 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="answer" id="answer-03">
    <p>Answer 3</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a `data` attribute with the answer id.
2. Add the eventListener to all questions at once using `jQuery(".all-questions").click`
3. use `jQuery('.answer'+jQuery(this).data('answer')).show();` to show current answer.
   `this` will use current element.
4. use `jQuery(this).addClass("highlighted");` to add the class to current element
5. To add the slide number, use `slideNumber = jQuery(this).data('answer');`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  "use strict";

  jQuery(".all-answers").hide();
  jQuery(".answer1").show();
  jQuery(".all-questions").removeClass("highlighted");
  jQuery(".question1").addClass("highlighted");

  var slideNumber = 1;
  jQuery(".all-questions").click(function() {
    jQuery(".all-answers").hide();
    jQuery('.answer'+jQuery(this).data('answer')).show();
    jQuery(".all-questions").removeClass("highlighted");
    jQuery(this).addClass("highlighted");
    slideNumber = jQuery(this).data('answer');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq-carousel">
  <div data-answer="1" class="all-questions question1">
    <h4>Question 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div data-answer="2" class="all-questions question2">
    <h4>Question 2</h4>
  </div>
  <div data-answer="3" class="all-questions question3">
    <h4>Question 3</h4>
  </div>

  <div class=" all-answers answer1">
    <p>Answer 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class=" all-answers answer2">
    <p>Answer 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class=" all-answers answer3">
    <p>Answer 3</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give all questions and answer elements a data-number attribute with the correct number then use

```
$(".all-questions").click(function() {
    $(".all-questions").hide();
    var slideNumber = $(this).data("number");
    $(".answer"+slideNumber).show();
    $(".all-questions").removeClass("highlighted");
    $(this).addClass("highlighted");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With no changes to the HTML, something like this should do it :

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $('.all-questions').on('click', function() {
        $('.all-answers').hide().filter('.answer' + $(this).index()).show();
        $('.all-questions').removeClass('highlighted').filter(this).addClass('highlighted');

    });

    $(".question1").trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Very simple. The trick I used is to associated every question class name with it's answers class name. For instance, if Question 1 class name is `question1`, its answer class name is `question1_answer`. After that let the magic happen (you can add your style however you want. Just copy/paste and run that code an see what it does.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>

        function myFunction(classname){

            var answerClassName = "." + classname + '_answer';
            $(answerClassName).show();

            //Hide all other answers
            var otherAnswers = document.body.getElementsByTagName("div");
            var l = otherAnswers.length;

            for(i=0 ; i<l ;i++){

                if(otherAnswers[i].className == classname){
                    //do nothing
                }else{
                    var otherAnswersClassName = "." + otherAnswers[i].className + '_answer';
                    jQuery(otherAnswersClassName).hide();
                }
            }
        }

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="question1" onclick="myFunction(this.className)">
            <h4>Question 1</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="question1_answer">
            <p>Answer 1</p>
        </div> 

        <div class="question2" onclick="myFunction(this.className)">
            <h4>Question 2</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="question2_answer">
            <p>Answer 2</p>
        </div> 
    </body>

</html>
```